# R ggplot2 barplot: vary distance between bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, space

In a bar plot, I want to have one bar separated from the rest. Say we have this data frame:

```
Testdata <- data.frame(var_1 = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "f"), var_2 = c(10, 15, 20, 25, 30))
```

Using the basic barplot function this can be done with the space command.

```
barplot(height=Testdata$var_2, names=Testdata$var_1, space=c(0.1,1,0.1,0.1,0.1) )
```

But that won't work if using ggplot2:

```
ggplot(Testdata, aes(var_1, var_2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", space=c(0.1,1,0.1,0.1,0.1))
```

Is there a way to get such an effect with ggplot?

Comment: `ggplot(Testdata, aes(var_1, var_2)) + geom_col() + scale_x_discrete(limits = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "f"))` This is a hack though, and could get fixed in a later update.

Comment: Another option would be to convert `var_1` as numeric with the positions you want, and define breaks and labels in `scale_x_continuous()` to be consistent with your discrete variables.